# How to install turtlegraphics in python

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I'm trying my hands on Turtle but I can't get the module installed.

I have searched a lot and people seems to imply that it is included in the Python
standard library with Tkinter but this doesn't seem to be the case for me.

when I do:

```
import Tkinter
```

everything seems ok. But when I try

```
t1 = Turtle()
```

I get the error

```
NameError: name 'Turtle' is not defined
```

As per the tutorial I'm suppose to import like this:

```
from turtlegraphics import Turtle
```

But no matter what I've tried I cant find how I can get the library installed.

Comment: Tried `import turtle`?

Comment: Check this: http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/turtle.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to import it from the `turtle` module.

```
from turtle import Turtle
t1 = Turtle()
t1.forward(100)
```

Comment: Note that on many platforms, the window will close immediately without `t1.getscreen().exitonclick()` at the end.

Answer (score -1):

Try to check within the library files whether there is a file called turtle in it . I had the same problem and i found the library file and opened it. So check it and see if it will fix your problem. Most probably turtle library file will be in Lib folder.

Answer (score -1):

Nothing here worked for me. This is what I did: I checked what configuration I had (in the upper right hand corner). I changed it so it was the python version that ran through the project and not just plain python. Then you also have to go to script path (also a setting in the configuation) and set it to the .py that you are working on :)